# How to echo multiple lines?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I have such lines:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  $brand.mydomain.com;
    root         /srv/www/clients/$brand/soon;
}
```

How could I append all those lines at once to the end of /etc/nginx/sites-available/default ?

Wrapping this text in this:

```
cat >/etc/nginx/sites-available/default  <<'EOT'
  EOT
```

works, but it erases all the content in the file. I want to append. Tried wrapping with this:

```
  cat >/etc/nginx/sites-available/default  >>'EOT'
  EOT
```

but the script just hangs.

Comment: `cat >> file` to append because `cat> file` will recreate the file. In your case `cat >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append to a file you should use `>>`.
If the file exist the output of the command will be appended to the file.
If it doesn't exist it will be created as if you used a single `>`.

In your case the solution that worked substituting `>> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default` instead of `> ...` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `>>` instead of `>` to append text to a file:

```
$ cat >> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default  <<'EOT'
```